# Check if in Bash/Linux

Tags: bash

I have a problem with this condition:

```
echo ${0##*/} # result: bady

my if: if [[ "$(pgrep -c "${0##*/}")" -eq 1 ]]... check OK!

edit if: if [[ "$(pgrep -c "bady")" -eq 1 ]]... check problem!
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

You have double quotes, change to:

```
if [[ "$(pgrep -c bady)" -eq 1 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (( $(pgrep -c bady) == 1 ))
```

No need to quote an integer.

**Note** : `((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Answer (score 0):

Do you really care if the count is 1, or do you just need to differentiate between "matched" and "not matched", and the count just happens to be 1? You can just check the exit status of `pgrep` to see if a match occurred:

```
if pgrep "${0##*/}"; then
```